# I'm trying to make a function that filters the last working day of the month, I'm having a problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

This function is taking the last working day of the previous month. Assuming that when the last business day of the previous month falls on a Friday, I need to fall on the next business day, which in this case would be a Monday. But it's falling on a Saturday. How do I integrate so it only drops on weekdays? And how can I integrate the holidays?

I already have an existing holiday table

```
import calendar
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

def BsDay():
    today = date.today()
    last_day = max(calendar.monthcalendar(today.year, today.month)[-1:][0][:5])
    validDay = (today.year, today.month-1,
                max(calendar.monthcalendar(today.year, today.month-1)[-1:][0][:5]))
    if today.month == 1 and today.day <= last_day:
        validDay = (today.year-1, today.month+11,
                    max(calendar.monthcalendar(today.year, today.month-1)[-1:][0][:5]))

    elif today.day <= last_day:
        validDay
    else:
        validDay = (today.year, today.month, max(
            calendar.monthcalendar(today.year, today.month)[-1:][0][:5]))

    return validDay
```

I tried to do this calculation but it is not working.

```
BusinessDay = ''.join(map(str, BsDay()))
BusinessDay = BusinessDay[0:4] + '-0' + BusinessDay[4]+'-'+BusinessDay[5:7]

dateD='2022-07-29'
dateD=pd.to_datetime(dateD)
dateF=pd.to_datetime(BusinessDay)

LastDayNotWeekend=dateD+timedelta(days=1)
print('LastDayNotWeekend not Weekend',LastDayNotWeekend)
LastDayInWeekend=dateF+timedelta(days=1)
print('LastDayInWeekend in Weekend->',LastDayInWeekend)
```

Output of the variable where the last working day of the month does not fall on a weekend.

```
LastDayNotWeekend not Weekend 2022-07-30 00:00:00
```

Output of the variable where the last working day of the month falls on a weekend.

```
LastDayInWeekend in Weekend-> 2022-09-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: There is a code gap at your function BsDay(). You should edit your question, please.

elif today.day <= last_day:
        validDay  ??????

Comment: Could you demonstrate how this gap would look?